# How can I make a form which properly calls an action which uses generics?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, generics, razor

In ASP.NET MVC3 C#, I want to have an action with this signature:

```
public ActionResult Restore<T>(int entityId, string redirect) where T : class
```

I cannot figure out how to call this action properly from the view through a user action. Is it possible to pass the type like that from a view?

Perhaps with something similar to:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Restore", "Global", new { T = @m }))
```

Perhaps the signature could change while retaining the functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do this out of the box.  What it boils down to is that the routing code is not generic type aware.  Generic types are stored internally much different than they are represented in code, as such method names are not compared the same way.

It could be possible if you wrote your own extension points, but there could be other problems with code that doesn't expect this behavior.  You would also have to write many of your own helper methods and not use existing ones.

In short, it's not worth trying to do in my opinion.

Comment: Okay, so using generics in that fashion is out of the question. What if I passed the model object into the action?

Comment: @TravisJ - I don't understand.  What model object?  You didn't provide one.  What are you actually asking?

Comment: In the view, the viewmodel would have an object - lets call its Box (@m.Box). I could pass that object into the action. I am trying to make a global action for some basic repetitive crud operations.